# Using a JLabel to count total coins?

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

For programming coursework I have to make a Java game with a shop...so basically you be a superhero and fight crimes for fighting the crime you are rewarded with coins but I don't no how to implement this I originally thought of a jprogressbar but this then meant there was a limit to the number of coins u could collect so my lecturer suggest using a JLabel but didn't explain how this works can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following way you can update your label.

```
JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel();
int counter = 0;

public void coinGained() {
 counter++;
 scoreLabel.setText(""+counter);

}
```